# CSS: conditional formatting based on class of adjacent elements

Tags: css

I have a few adjacent `span` tags that are styled to be `display: inline-block;` like so:

```css
span.mark {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p>Some <span class="mark">standalone</span> test. Some <span class="mark">continuous </span><span class="mark">elements </span><span class="mark">that</span> should be formatted together.</p>

<p>Some <span class="mark">normal </span><b><span class="mark">and strong</span></b> text that should be formatted together.</p>
```

So currently these `span` tags all get their own little borders. However, I want them to look like there's just one border around them all together. So, technicall, the outer ones should have `border-width-left: 1px;` for the first one and `border-width-right: 1px;` for the last one and the ones in the middle should have `border-width: 1px 0px;`.

Is there a way to do this in CSS? Basically the rule should be: "If this is a span with a mark class and the elements before and after me are spans with a mark class then apply middle element styling. If this is a span with a mark class and the element before me is not a element with a mark style and the element after me is a span element with a mark style, apply left element styling. Etc..."

I know there is `span.mark:before` and `span.mark:after`, but I don't actually want to style the element before or after the current one. I want to style the current one best on what comes before and after it. Also, I need to check for the class of the `:before` and `:after` elements.

**edit:**
Maybe my example was too simplistic. There will be more than one string of `<span>` tags in a given `<p>`. The whole `:first-of-type` `:last-of-type` is looking very promising, I didn't know about those. I'm afraid the solution will be more complicated though, if it works at all...

Comment: span.comment or span.mark?

Comment: span.mark - stupid copy and paste mistake

Comment: There's no way to do *exactly* what you ask; at maximum, you could use `:first-child` and `:last-child` to differentiate the first one and the last one.

Comment: The answer isn't actually correct, you can select adjacent elements by class / tag / id (or other typical CSS selector) by simply using a `+` between them...ie `span.mark + .mark { border-left: none; }`. This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector) as well.

Comment: Take a look and give me your thoughts: https://jsfiddle.net/42x9ugbe/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError that's a pretty sweet solution! I'll have to play around with it some more but I like it. Very pragmatic and sidestepping many problems since it works on a visual basis and not a structural one.

Comment: Great, I'll be anticipating any further feedback. I'm considering posting this solution as an official answer, as it may prove useful to other readers as well.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError That solution is great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the support of *pseudo-elements* and a combination of `absolute` positioning and *stacking context* the intended behaviour can be achieved.

The snippet embedded below demonstrates how every preceding element's *pseudo-element* is stacked below the following element; conveying the impression of seamless continuity while still maintaining the visual impression of a full border for stand-alone elements.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
span.mark {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

span.mark:after,
span.mark:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    /* for border-radius */
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: yellow;
    width: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

span.mark:after {
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    right: -2px;
}

span.mark:before {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    left: -2px;
}
```

```html
<p>Some <span class="mark">standalone</span> test. Some <span class="mark">continuous </span><span class="mark">elements </span><span class="mark">that</span> should be formatted together.</p>

<p>Some <span class="mark">normal </span><b><span class="mark">and strong</span></b> text that should be formatted together.</p>
```

Comment: That's clever, very clever!

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I would use the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo-selector to style the first/last span differently to the rest.
See https://jsfiddle.net/samando27/xydqpbx8/1/

Comment: Sorry mate, your answer isn't actually correct, you can use `+` to select next sibling and `~` to sibling that comes further down the DOM (not specifically the next one). Here's another question/answer for further reference -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)